# How do I let a parent window access my frame's content if I control the frame?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a little script that has to open an API window like:

```js
var api = window.open("https://example.com", "Poppout", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=350,height=400,top="+(screen.height-400)+",left="+(screen.width-840));
```

when ever I try to access it like:
`api.document.getElementById('ex').value;`
I get the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:5
```

I know why this is happening but since I'm the owner of the API's url can I enable this some way?

My `index.js` code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path')
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const i = new Server(server);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next();
 });
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'))
});
app.use('/', router);

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { chat, username } = req.body;
  console.log(username, '÷', chat)
  i.emit('chat', chat, username);
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on port: 3000');
});
```

Comment: What domains are you actually using? You might need to use cross-origin messaging.

Comment: https://chat-api.penguinpowers.repl.co/ and any other website, not targeting a single one.

Comment: So you want any other website to include a script snippet that would allow them to open a popup with your website?

Comment: yes but i already have that, the problem is accessing the html in the popup without violating CORS, the popup consistently updates so it needs a constant window with access.

Comment: Do you even need a popup? Wouldn't an in-page dialog be more appropriate? And why does the embedding page need to access the popup html?

Comment: the html on the popup stores the username and message that a user would sent to another persons ex: user picks there name to be "person1", then they send a message to the API, "Hello World" the api receives "person1 : Hello World", then it sends a webhook to the html page saying "person1 : HelloWorld" the html adds a <LI> tag with "person1 : Hello world" another person say "person2" on there computer the webpage is scanning the popup(api) for a new message, checks if it was sent by itself or another person if another person sent it it alerts the message to person2. Its like a portable chat.

Comment: "*the webpage is scanning the popup(api) for a new message*" - don't do that. It sounds like polling. Either let the webpage directly talk to your api, e.g. using a websocket (not sure what you meant by "webhook"), or have your popup page send chat events to the opener via [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Then let the webpage simply *listen* after opening the popup.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install cors `npm i cors`
2. import cors and use it to manage cross orign requests

   const cors = require('cors');

   app.use(cors());  //allow any url

   app.options('*', cors())

**You can also whitelist specific Urls by setting cors options Origin value:**

```
const cors = require('cors');
       
    
const corsOptions = {
origin: [
 'https://example.com',
'https://yourURL.com',
'http://anotherURL.com
],
optionSuccessStatus:200, //for Legacy browsers

}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: i still get the same error, i added "cors" and alowed all do you know why it isnt working?